# How does Udacity create presentation where the text is in front and video in back? See pic

Tags: image, video, overlay, layer

How does Udacity.com (new learning website) create presentation where the text is in front the video is in back? Is there any specific software they use to prepare the presentations?

[image]

Comment: Could simply be an image overlay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Udacity is using [Wacom Cintiq tablet](http://www.wacom.com/en/Products/Cintiq.aspx) for producing those presentations.

Answer (score 9):

Some extra information to add on [Suhair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38807/suhair)'s info about the Wacom Cintiq tablet being used.

Katy Reichelt is in charge of the video editing process and she explains how it has evolved and how it is done [in her blog](http://udacity.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/katy-reichelt-on-video-editing-and.html).

In that post you will find a link to professor's John Regehr recollection of **[how the class is recorded](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/716)**:

> The recording process is this. You shut yourself into a dark, soundproofed room, put on a mic, and turn on a video camera and a program that records the tablet. Then, record written and spoken material. The editors can remove bad takes and pauses, which after years of lecturing to a live audience was hard for me to internalize. However, in the end it was very freeing since I could draw pictures, change colors, lookup details on Wikipedia, and attempt to write neatly (always a struggle for me) — all without boring anyone except the editors.The editors are 100% crucial to what Udacity is doing, and the difference between unedited material and the final output is striking. I can’t say enough about how good their work is.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is something like the following: 
[Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Srt07MIrRRo&feature=player_detailpage#t=190s)